# Objective-C: Back Button disappear after present/push ViewController from AppsDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate, back-button

The pic below is my storyboard and I wish to present the `Upcoming VC` at `AppDelegate`. Below is my code at `AppDelegate` I manage to present the `Upcoming VC` when called.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc=[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Upcoming"];
UINavigationController *nv = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
nv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nv animated:YES completion:nil];
```

At the `Upcoming VC`, I manage to present the `navigationBar with title and background colour` but my back button `<` remain missing. My back button is auto generated.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:FALSE];
    //====Make the navigation Bar appear===
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;

    //=== Set the navigation Back < color
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor : [ UIColor grayColor]];
    //=== Set the navigation Bar text color
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar
    setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

}

Please help.

[image: Pic1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect then ?

back button will be only visible when you push your `UpcomingVC` from existing ViewController
remember that just taking navigation bar in storyboard will now show backbutton automatically.

You can  create full view controller  hierarchy

Like

`UpcomingVC` is pushed from `HomeVC` then you can set `HomeVC` as root view controller embedded in `UINavigationController` and to the next line you can push 
`UpcomingVC` with animation  false

Answer (score 0):

you can tyr this
StoryBoard to StoryBoard

```
ViewControllerName * next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerName"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
```

you must be nib registered.